# How to move a button value from a component to another component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a calculator app, where there are 3 main components involved. The top bar where the title of the app is and a switch that switches themes, a screen component which displays the arithmetic operations and their results and a keypad component that holds all available clickable numbers and mathematical operations. I used Chakra UI library to build my app.
Is there a way to take the value of a button in the keypad component and 'send' it to the screen component where the arithmetic would happen ?

```
import * as React from "react"
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Box,
  Text,
  Flex,
  Center,
  Spacer,
  Container,
  VStack,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Switch,
  useColorMode,
  useColorModeValue,
  Input,
  Grid,
  GridItem
} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import "@fontsource/spartan/700.css"
import customTheme from "./theme"
import CalculatorButton from "./button-component";
import FunctionalButton from "./function-component";

export default function App(){
  

  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
    <Box bg={"bisque"} color={"white"} h="100vh">
      {/* Main App Container */}
      <Box>
        <Center>
          <VStack>
            {/* Top bar */}
            {TopBar()}
            {/* Result Display */}
            {DisplayResult()}
            {/* Keys pad */}
            {KeypadButtons()}
          </VStack>
        </Center>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

```
function TopBar() {
  return (
    <Container p="0">
      <Flex align="center" justify="space-between">
      <Box>
        <Text fontSize="22" fontWeight="bold">calc</Text>
      </Box>
      <Spacer />
      <Box>
        <FormControl display="flex" alignItems="center">
          <FormLabel htmlFor="theme-switch" mb="0" fontSize="9">
            THEME
          </FormLabel>
          <Switch id="theme-switch" size="sm" />
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
      </Flex>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

```
function DisplayResult() {
  interface CalculatorData {
    value:number,
    prevState:null,
  }
  const [value,setValue] = useState<CalculatorData | null>(null);
  return (
    <Box size="lg" mb="2" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <Input
      placeholder="0"
      textAlign="right"
      p="10"
      bg={darkSaturatedBlue.screenBackgroundColor}
      border="none"
      fontSize="23"
      // value={value}
      // onChange={(e)=>setValue(parseInt(e.target.value))}
       />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

```
function KeypadButtons() {
  return <Container bg={darkSaturatedBlue.toggleKeybadBackgroundColor} borderRadius="3" p="3">
    <Grid templateColumns="repeat(4,1fr)" templateRows="repeat(5,1fr)" gap="2">
      <CalculatorButton digit={7} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor} />
      <CalculatorButton digit={8} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <CalculatorButton digit={9} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <FunctionalButton digit={"DEL"} color="white" size="md" boxShadow="md"  />
      <CalculatorButton digit={4} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <CalculatorButton digit={5} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <CalculatorButton digit={6} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <FunctionalButton digit={"+"} color="white" size="md" boxShadow="md" />
      <CalculatorButton digit={1} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <CalculatorButton digit={2} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <CalculatorButton digit={3} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <FunctionalButton digit={"-"} color="white" size="md" boxShadow="md" />
      <FunctionalButton digit={"."} color="white" size="md" boxShadow="md" />
      <CalculatorButton digit={0} color="white" size="md" bg={darkSaturatedBlue.buttonDigitColor}/>
      <FunctionalButton digit={"/"} color="white" size="md" boxShadow="md" />
      <FunctionalButton digit={"x"} color="white" size="md"  boxShadow="md"/>
      <GridItem colSpan={2}>
        <FunctionalButton digit={"RESET"} color="teal" size="md" style={buttonStyle} boxShadow="md" />
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem colSpan={2}>
        <FunctionalButton digit={"="} color="red" size="md" style={buttonStyle} boxShadow="md" />
      </GridItem>
    </Grid>
  </Container>;
}
```

*Calculator Button.tsx*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button} from '@chakra-ui/react';


const CalculatorButton: React.FC<{digit:Number,color:string,bg?:string,size:string}> = ({digit,color,bg,size}) => {
    return (
        <Button colorScheme="White" size={size} m="1" bg={bg} variant="solid">
            {digit}
        </Button>
    );
}

export default CalculatorButton;
```

*Function Component.tsx*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button} from '@chakra-ui/react';

const FunctionalButton : React.FC<{digit:string,color:string,boxShadow:string,size:string,style?:object}> = ({digit,color,boxShadow,size,style}) => {
    return (
        <Button colorScheme={color} size={size} sx={style} m="1" boxShadow={boxShadow}>
            {digit}
        </Button>
    )
}

export default FunctionalButton;
```

Comment: Why are you calling your React components as functions instead of JSX? If you need to send pressed key data back out from the keypad component then it needs to be passed a callback function to do so. Perhaps something like an `onKeyPress` callback.

Comment: I was refactoring my code and I happened to make it a function. Thanks, I'll try a different approach.